# issue with a border on a vertical menu using css on a divi theme

Tags: css

I added this css code

```
 /* header right border */
    #main-header {border-right: 6px solid #f49200;}
```

When I hover on a page in the menu, the dropdown submenu opens,
when I move my curser towards the dropdown submenu, as my curser comes in contact with the border,  the dropdown submenu hides.

Comment: please write some working code or explain a little more.

Comment: I am pretty sure that's not the issue, if you can post more complete code (simplified example) I am sure we can get to the bottom of it

Comment: Basically he explains that the `:hover` state is not active when hovering the border of the div

Comment: correct, the border is acting as a shield between the menu and dropdown submenu

Comment: not sure why it isn't working on your end, this pen works:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvRVxW

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `border-right`, use `padding-right` and `background` with an inner content `div` to achieve the same thing:

```css
#main-header {
  background: #f49200;
  padding-right: 6px;
}
#main-header-content {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-header">
  <div id="main-header-content">Stuff goes here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited the question, this code did not work for me, not sure why!